# How do I use Photon Unity Networking with my custom server?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unityscript, photon

I was just wondering how I would use Photon Unity Networking (PUN) with my own custom server. I am not talking about Photon Cloud or Photon Server but a server that I have setup.

Please try to be as simple as possible :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Photon Unity Networking** implements a relatively complex message protocol and communication workflow. It is not a simple wrapper around sockets or something like that, so it only communicates with Photon Servers - no matter if in the Photon Cloud or if you host your own Photon instance(s).

The best of both worlds might be using the Photon Server SDK, which comes with a project called "Load Balancing". This is more or less the logic that runs in the Photon Cloud and while it's compatible with PUN, you might edit it into whatever you need.

The download is [here](https://www.exitgames.com/OnPremise/Download).